# Faster when I save the result of a method in a new variable?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management

I was wondering if it is any helpful helpful for the performance (next to the readability) when I save the result of a method in a new variable for further uses. My thought was, that like this the method only needs to be processed once or is this a misunderstanding and only a waste of memory?

Here I save the result of a method because I will use it multiple times.

```
  byte[] headerAsArray = getHeaderByteArray(currentResponse.getHttpResponse(), currentResponse.getOriginalHost(), currentResponse.getOriginalURI());
        bb.writeInt(headerAsArray.length);
        bb.writeBytes(headerAsArray);
```

Comment: The best way to look at what the code is doing is looking at its bytecode: `javap -c <class>`

Comment: compiler optimization is there to avoid waste of memory so if compiler optimization is active, it will take care of it. personally I make the code more readable and leave the rest to the compiler

Comment: @Pooya: The compiler *won't* remove a second call to `getHeaderByteArray` here...

Comment: it depends on the context

Comment: @JonSkeet the concern was about wasting memory by storing results which in my opinion is not the waste

Comment: @Pooya: Your comment was very ambiguous then - I read it as "don't bother with that optimization - the compiler will do it for you."

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you're trying to avoid `getHeaderByteArray` from being called multiple times, then yes, you're doing exactly the right thing. The "cost" of having one extra local variable is negligible in almost *all* cases. I'd say it's also more readable than the alternative of:

```
bb.writeInt(getHeaderByteArray(currentResponse.getHttpResponse(), currentResponse.getOriginalHost(), currentResponse.getOriginalURI()).length);
bb.writeBytes(getHeaderByteArray(currentResponse.getHttpResponse(), currentResponse.getOriginalHost(), currentResponse.getOriginalURI()));
```

That's awful! It might also be incorrect, if for some reason `getHeaderByteArray()` can return different results for each call. (Unlikely in this case, but possible in general. There's a big difference between calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` twice, and calling it once and using the result twice, for example.)

I would probably refactor it further though, by adding a method accepting whatever the type of `currentResponse` is. Then you can change your code to:

```
byte[] header = getHeaderBytes(currentResponse);
bb.writeInt(header.length);
bb.writeBytes(header);
```

If you find yourself writing code like this a lot though, you might *also* want to write a method which accepts a byte array and writes the length and then the bytes. At *that* point you could write:

```
writeDataWithLengthPrefix(getHeaderBytes(currentResponse));
```

Comment: Assuming my byte array is huge (10 Mb)  the cost would be probably to high for an extra local variable? (That's not the case here, but I ask for general understanding)

Comment: @HerrDerb: No, because the extra local variable is just a reference to a byte array object. It's really important that you understand that the value of a variable is never an object - it's only ever a primitive value, or a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, by saving the result of the method in a variable you avoid calling it multiple times, thus reducing the complexity. The only space that is wasted is the size of the byte array However, you would need the byte array later on so I wouldn't call it a waste. Hope I understood your question.

Comment: The size of the byte array is *not* wasted. Potentially the size of a *reference* is wasted, but that's very different. If `getHeaderByteArray` returns a new byte array every time, the local variable is actually *saving* the size of the byte array in terms of avoiding a new allocation.